# How do I calculate size of a compressed object?

Tags: javascript, object, compression, sizeof

How do I calculate the actual size of a object or compressed object(Bytes) in javascript,and not based on length of characters in the object?

I tried object-sizeof npm library,but it returns size based on length of characters.In the below code jsonCompressCheck is a large Json Object which I need to compress and I want to get the sizes so that I know how efficient it is

```
console.log("Actual Object Size: "+sizeof($scope.jsonCompressCheck));
var zlib = require('zlib');
var sizeof = require('object-sizeof');
  zlib.deflate(JSON.stringify($scope.jsonCompressCheck),function(err, buffer) {
            if (!err) {
              console.log("USing Deflate Size of: ");
              console.log("Byte Length: "+Buffer.byteLength(buffer));
              console.log(sizeof(buffer));
             $scope.compressed = buffer;
            }
          });
     zlib.gzip(JSON.stringify($scope.jsonCompressCheck),function(err, buffer) {
            if (!err) {
              console.log("USing gzip: ");
              console.log("Byte Length: "+Buffer.byteLength(buffer));
              console.log(sizeof(buffer));
             $scope.compressed = buffer;
            }
          });
```

Comment: Add a snippet of code of what you tried so far and where you got stuck. Please avoid posting again before reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question on Stack Overflow. Oh, and please edit this question...

Comment: I have added the code can you answer now?

Comment: My knwoledge in js is very limited, I was just trying to help you in order to avoid future errors, and stop getting downvoted or a very few will see your question. Anyway now it respect the standard of this community, upvote for you.